# When $4^x+9^y$ is a multiple of $37$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to find all $(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^{\geq 0} \times \mathbb Q^{\geq 0}$ such that $4^x+9^y$ is a multiple of $37$ ?

---

Let $u=2x,~v=2y$, then the problem reduces to $$2^u+3^v \equiv 0~(\text{mod}~37)~----->(A)$$

My approach will be to fix one variable $u$ and find all possible values $v$ in equation $(A)$.

- Fix $u=0$, so that $(A)$ becomes $$3^v \equiv -1~(\text{mod}~37),$$
  which has first solution $v=9$. Since $3$ has order $37$ in $\mathbb Z_{37}$, so that all $v=9+37k,~k=0,1,2 \cdots$ are solutions.
  Therefore $(u,v)=(0,9+37k)$ are solutions of $(A)$. Note that $(9+37k,0)$ are also solutions if we have fixed $v=0$.
- Fix $u=1$, so that $(A)$ becomes $$3^v \equiv -3~(\text{mod}~37),$$
  which has first solution $v=10$. Since $3$ has order $37$ in $\mathbb Z_{37}$, so that all $v=10+37k,~k=0,1,2 \cdots$ are solutions.
  Therefore $(u,v)=(1,10+37k)$ are solutions of $(A)$. Note that $(10+37k,1)$ are also solutions if we have fixed $v=1$.
- The same way one can proceed.

Now if we plot the the solutions $(x,y)=(0,\frac{9+37k}{2}),~(\frac{9+37k}{2},0),~(\frac{1}{2},\frac{10+37k}{2}),~(\frac{10+37k}{2},\frac{1}{2}),~ \cdots$, we can see two types of families of straight lines. The family (say, C) of lines joining the points $(\frac{9+37k}{2},0)$ and $(\frac{10+37k}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ will have positive slopes while the family (say, D) of lines joining the points $(0,\frac{9+37k}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{10+37k}{2})$ will have negative slopes.

Now the set of all possible intersections of the lines of C with the lines of D gives us all possible $(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^{\geq 0} \times \mathbb Q^{\geq 0}$ such that $4^x+9^y$ is a multiple of $37$.

The above approach I can think of.

Are there other suitable methods to find the points $(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^{\geq 0} \times \mathbb Q^{\geq 0}$ such that $4^x+9^y$ is a multiple of $37$ ?

Thanks

Comment: My claim is the following: Since $(4,9)=1$ then $(4^n,9^y)$ is also coprime each other. Therefore, it is impossible to find such $x$ and $y$ since the sum can not be $37$.So, you can eliminate solution for $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Another way to reason this lattice out is that, modulo 37, one has $2^2=3^7$. One can show from this that $(n,m)$ is a solution iff $(n+2,m+7)$ is also a solution. Similarly, from $2^4=3^{-4}$ mod 37 one has $(n,m)$ a solution iff $(n+4,m-4)$ is also a solution. So if we start from one solution---say, $(n,m)=(0,9)$---then we generate a lattice of such solutions.  (Tho tbh, this essentially feels like another way to package what's already in the post...)

Comment: @FuatRay, I am not sure what do you mean

Comment: @Semiclassical, very interesting. Do you see the solutions $(n,m)$ forms a lattice. Because in that case, sum of any two solutions $(n_1,m_1)$ and $(n_2,m_2)$ have to be a solution, again. For example, if we start with $(n,m)=(0,9)$ then $(2,16),~(4,23),~\cdots$ are solutions. What would be the basis of this lattice ?

Comment: That's not quite right: for instance, you can't add $(0,9)$ to itself to get $(0,18)$ as a solution. But we can write, for instance, $(n,m)=(0,9)+j(2,7)+k(4,-4)$ for integer $j,k$. So we can view this as an affine lattice: that is, a lattice shifted from the origin. In this case, the shift can be chosen as $(0,9)$ and the basis as $\{(2,7), (4,-4)\}$. (As a side comment: If $2^n,3^m$ are interpreted as inverse powers for negative $n,m$, then this affine lattice extends across all of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ rather than just the positive quadrant.)

Comment: @Semiclassical, beautiful comment. Thank you very much

Comment: Observe that, by Little Fermat, $2^a$ and $2^b$ are congruent modulo $37$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $36$. After all, $2^{36}\equiv1=2^0\pmod{37}$. In other words, you must look at the exponents modulo $36$ instead of $37$. Because $2$ is a primitive root modulo $37$, it follows that $2^a\equiv2^b$ if and only if $a\equiv b\pmod{16}$. But $3$ is a quadratic residue, so the remainders of powers of $3$ start repeating with half the period, and further checking reveals that $3^a\equiv3^b$ if and only if $a\equiv b\pmod{18}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not difficult to show that for $u,v\in\Bbb{Q}$ the number $S(u,v):=2^u+3^v$ is a rational number if and only if both $u$ and $v$ are integers. This is because the fields $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/r})$ and $\Bbb{Q}(3^{1/s})$ intersect trivially whenever $r,s$ are integers $>1$ (it follows that unless $u,v$ are both non-negative we cannot have $S(u,v)\in\Bbb{Z}$). Therefore $u$ and $v$ must both be natural numbers (I include zero).

A quick check shows that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $37$. In other words it has multiplicative order $36$. This means that we can apply base $2$ [discrete logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) that now take values in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{36}$. Obviously
$$
\log_2(-1)=18,
$$
because $-1$ has multiplicative order two, and $18=36/2$. Checking the list of powers of $2$ reveals that $$\log_2(3)=26$$
as $2^{26}\equiv3\pmod{37}$.

Putting these together it follows that
$$
-3^v\equiv 2^{18}\cdot2^{26v}=2^{18+26v}\pmod{37}.
$$
So $37\mid 2^u+3^v$ if and only if the natural numbers $u,v$ satisfy the congruence
$$
u\equiv 18+26v\pmod{36}.
$$

---

This means that we can let $v$ be any natural numbers, and the choice of $v$ determines a unique residue class modulo $36$ where $u$ must come from.
That additive constant $+18$ means that we get a coset of a lattice in the first quadrant as the set of solutions.

Comment: Ask, if the use of discrete logarithms is not clear.

Comment: I didn't check MSE for last $2$ days, so sorry for late reply. I appreciate the clear nice answer. I can understand the use of discrete logarithm. But can please explain the first $2$ lines of your answer little bit more ? It seems $S(u,v):=2^u+3^v$ will be rational number if $u,v \in \mathbb Z$ but I didn't get the field theoretic argument you used. Ofcourse $\mathbb Q(2^{1/r}) \cap \mathbb Q(3^{1/s})=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Another comment: If I am correct then we can use both the phrase "coset of lattice" or "affine lattice". Ofcourse the first one you used here.

Comment: If neither $u$ nor $v$ is an integer, then $2^u$ and $3^v$ are irrational numbers in fields of the form $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/r})$, $\Bbb{Q}(3^{1/s})$ with $r,s>1$. If their sum were an integer $m$, then $2^u=m-3^v$ would be in the intersection of the two fields. But all the numbers in the intersection are rational. Seeing that is not trivial. I would use  Galois theory, but we probably have another thread for that. So $u$ and $v$ are integers. If either $u$ or $v$ is a negative inte, then $2^u+3^v$ is not an integer (its denominator is even if $u<0$ and divisible by $3$ if $v<0$.

Comment: May be algebraic number theory gives a cleaner argument? Like studying the ramification of the key primes $2$ and $3$ in those two fields.

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation. May be it is different question but I don't see how this same argument of discrete logarithm is useful for another congruence equation $2^x+3^y \equiv 0$ (mod $7$). Clearly, $2$ is primitive root of order $3$ modulo $7$, so we have $\log_2(-1)=3$. But we don't find any exponent $n$ such that $2^n \equiv 3$ (mod $7$). So I think we can not proceed with the same argument for $2^x+3^y \equiv 0$ (mod $7$). Any idea or am I wrong ?

Comment: $2$ is not a orimitive root modulo $7$. A primitive root modulo $7$ must have order six. Only $3$ and $5$ qualify. As $2$ generates a group of order three only, it follows that $-1$ is not a power of two at all. Indeed, $2^3\equiv1\pmod 7$.

Comment: Observe that  as three is a primitive root modulo $7$ you can use base $3$ discrete logarithms. $\log_3(-1)=3 \pmod6$ and $\log_32=2\pmod 6$ as $3^2\equiv2\pmod7$. So $2^x+3^y\equiv0\pmod7$ when $y\equiv3+2x\pmod 6$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your argument is nice, i have checked couple of other similar congruence equations modulo $n$, and this method is working when $n$ has some primitive root. For example, I checked it for $2^x+5^y \equiv 0$ (mod $11$). Your method is working, i.e., we can solve it similarly. So my intuition says your method should solve (at least conjecturally)  the congruence equation $a^x+b^y \equiv 0$ (mod $n$) when $n$ has primitive roots.

Comment: For example, I want to try to solve $a^x+b^y \equiv 0$ (mod $ab+1$). I assume $p:=ab+1$ is a prime, where $a,b>1$. Then of-course Fermat's theorem says $a^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$) as well as $b^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$). Adding both we have $a^{ab}+b^{ab} \equiv 2 \not\equiv 0$ (mod $p$). So it does not work. But I think your method will work here. Since $ab+1$ is prime, it has total $ab$ primitive roots, and so we can apply discrete logarithm argument. What do you say ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't know what [a primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) is. A primitive root is an integer $a$, $0<a<p$, such that the remainders of the powers $a^j, j=0,1,2,\ldots,p-2$, are all the numbers $1,2,\ldots,p-1$, without repetitions. Modulo a prime $p$ there are exactly $\phi(p-1)$ primitive roots (not $p-1$ as you seem to think). To be able to work discrete logarithms, the base usually needs to be a primitive root. Otherwise the logarithms may not exist (as you saw in the case $p=7$, $a=2$).

Comment: Test it for a few small cases to get a bit of confidence.

Comment: Sorry for typo, indeed I meant $\varphi(ab)$ primitive roots modulo $ab+1$ (letting it a prime). Thank you for correction. In the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) you provided, I got a table of primitive roots modulo $n$ upto $n=31$. And i can see from the table that if $ab+1$ is prime, then most of times either $a$ or $b$ is primitive roots. This motivates the following comment: